# How to set css to a specific selector using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

Consider the following HTML:

```
<div class="bl-dark separator">
    <div class="bl-icon-wrapper">
        <div class="bl-icon-border"></div>
        <div class="bl-icon-scale-bg dark"></div>
        <div class="bl-icon-background"></div>
        <div class="bl-icon-dark icon"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When a click occurs by the user, the selector `bl-icon-wrapper` will have a class added using jQuery, so that updated html would be:

```
<div class="bl-dark separator">
    <div class="bl-icon-wrapper selected">
        <div class="bl-icon-border"></div>
        <div class="bl-icon-scale-bg dark"></div>
        <div class="bl-icon-background"></div>
        <div class="bl-icon-dark icon"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now in the CSS I would like to have this selector filled:

```
.selected .bl-icon-scale-bg {
     // I want css added from .js here
}
```

I don't want `.bl-icon-scale-bg` I want **this specific selector** (`.selected .bl-icon-scale-bg`) filled.

If I wanted to add css for `.bl-icon-scale-bg` I can easily do it with `.find()`, but I can't get this specific one filled.

The reason why I want to do this is that the value of the css will vary depending on the viewport. Since it requires some math the values can't be calculated with a simple `calc` function in CSS, so using jQuery is required. If there isn't any way to fill this specific CSS from jQuery I guess I will have to go around it with other jQuery functions.

Comment: Why don't you add an id the the specific selector you want and select it with `$('#IdYouGave')`

Comment: Please write question correctly. @RTZ.Mikasa

Comment: I don't get what is the question/issue here?!  `The reason why I want to do this is that the value of the css will...` Really sounds like a [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding to CSS file you should change css using the following:

```
$(".selected .bl-icon-scale-bg").css("prop", "value");
```

Comment: ah whoops, didn't add the '.' so it wasn't selecting the right selector, thought this property was deprecated or sth